# why is there an error: size is not a member of std?

Tags: c++, arrays, size

```
#include <iostream> // for std::cout
#include <iterator> // for std::size

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 };
    std::cout << "The array has: " << std::size(array) << " elements\n";

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, i got something like size is not a member of std. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe your compiler does not support C++ 17. You can use std::extent instead.

Comment: Maybe you did not set the flag for "use C++ standard 17" when compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either your compiler does not support C++ 17 or such a support  is not activated with a compiler option

In any case you can use the standard class template `std::extent` declared in the header `<type-traits>`. For example

```
#include <iostream> // for std::cout
#include <type_traits> // for std::extent

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21 };
    std::cout << "The array has: " << std::extent<decltype( array )>::value << " elements\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... and its friend `std::extent_v<decltype(array)>`.